# how do you share xml file between Fragments?

Tags: android, mvvm

I have two fragments with two different ViewModel. But they share the same XML layout. How can I make this happen?

The problem is in the xml

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <data>

        <variable
            name="myViewModel"
            type="com.myapp.ViewModelXXX? 1 or 2??" />
    </data>
</layout>
```

Comment: If you don't use data binding its pretty easy.  If you do-  putting the actual layout in a separate xml file and including it via the include tag might work.

Comment: I think it's going to be easy if you just make two different fragments.